# proper way to duplicate views in order ( like cells in a tableView )

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have a screen that shows textField for the user to fill and one textField with some number in it that is not editable ( located below all the other views ).

now the circumstances are changed and instead of getting 1 number to fill this textField I get an array with numbers ( can still get only 1 ) so in that case I need to make more textField underneath. no idea how to do it,

objective c, deployment target is 7.0
so no stackViews ( i thought to make one and just add more textFields inside ) and the only way I can think of doing it is programatically,

can anyone give me reference or guidance on how to do something like that ?
no idea where to start. 
or maybe there is a better way doing it that Im missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a UITableView would solve all your problems. If the list is a static one (i.e. it cannot change at runtime) you can create a static tableview. If it's not, then define a UITableViewCell and add it programmatically.

Comment: ow, I didn't know about static table. its perfect ! thanks